# Delete Orphaned Parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a relationship like so:

```
Parent
  has_many :children

Child
  belongs_to :parent
```

What I want to do is to delete the parent if there are no more children left. So to do this I have:

```
Child
    before_destroy :destroy_orphaned_parent

    def destroy_orphaned_parent
      parent.children.each do |c|
        return if c != self
      end
      parent.destroy
    end
```

This works fine, however I *also* want to cascade the delete of the parent to the child. E.g. I would normally do:

```
Parent
  has_many :children, :dependent => :destroy
```

This causes the WebRick server to crash when I test it. I assume this is due to an infinite loop of the last child deleting the parent deleting the child etc.

I am starting to think that there is a better way to do this? Anyone have any ideas? Is there a way to prevent this recursion?

Comment: Thought I'd add that `parent.destroy if parent.children.empty?` is more concise than that loop with an early exit in `destroy_orphaned_parent`.  

Also, if either the parent or the children don't need to do any clean up, you can use `delete` and `delete_all` instead of `destroy` and `destroy_all` to skip the callbacks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some Ideas:

- You could delete orphaned parents in
  an `after_destroy` (find them using a
  statement like the one on
  http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/a3f12d578f5a2619)
- You could set some instance variable in `before_destroy` containing the parent's ID, then do a lookup based on this id in an `after_destroy` callback and decide whether to delete the parent there based on counting the children

Comment: haven't tested this yet, but I think that the key is to move the logic to the after_destroy rather than the before_destroy as I had in my original post

Answer (score 8):

I accomplished this in the following way:

```
  before_destroy :find_parent
  after_destroy :destroy_orphaned_parent

  def find_parent
    @parent = self.parent
  end

  def destroy_orphaned_parent
    if @parent.children.length == 0
      @parent.destroy
    end  
  end
```

As per Anwar's suggestion, this can also be accomplished using an `around` callback, as follows:

```
  around_destroy :destroy_orphaned_parent

  def destroy_orphaned_parent
    parent = self.parent
    yield # executes a DELETE database statement
    if parent.children.length == 0
      parent.destroy
    end  
  end
```

I haven't tested the above solution, so feel free to update it, if necessary.

Comment: Instead of using before and after callback, around callback can also be used

Answer (score 3):

Use an `after_destroy` callback.

```
after_destroy :release_parent

def release_parent
  if parent.children.count.zero?
    parent.destroy
  end
end
```

Using Rails 3.2.15

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this using `around_destroy` callback

```
around_destroy :destroy_orphaned_parent

def destroy_orphaned_parent
  @parent = self.parent
  yield
  @parent.destroy if @parent.children.length == 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
after_destroy :destroy_parent, if: parent_is_orphan?

private

def parent_is_orphan?
 parent.children.count.zero?
end

def destroy_parent
 parent.destroy
end
```