# Rails: avoid recursive destroy callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, recursion, callback

I have two models:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :adverts, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :car

  # Destroy the car, if there is no more adverts left
  after_destroy do
    self.car.destroy unless self.car.adverts.exists?
  end
end
```

Now this works well when calling `advert.destroy`, but when calling `car.destroy`, things end up in a recursive loop!

PS. rails 4.1.8

Comment: The suggestion on checking for any adverts left is from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866378/delete-orphaned-parent, however it collides with having a `dependent: :destroy` on the relation.

Comment: It seems kind of related to this: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13609