# Rails - remove object if has no childs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm struggling with the following problem: how to force object to destroy when it has no childs (or more precisly last child got destroyed). I tried following soltions:

- Adding counter cache to the parent and destroing him if it is equal to 0, but then i couldn't create it using Factory Girl it was immediately destroyed.
- Last solution from [Delete Orphaned Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866378/delete-orphaned-parent), unfortunatelly it won't work with destroy_all - I'm getting stack overflow.

I cannot find any other up-to-date solution. Any one have any idea how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is in an `after_destroy` callback on the the child object.  Here's an example with two models named Parent and Child:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  after_destroy: :destroy_orphaned_parent

  def destroy_orphaned_parent
    parent.destroy if parent.children.empty?
  end
end
```

This solution works fine with `destroy_all` and will work for creating Parent records with no children in FactoryGirl.

Comment: It does work when you remove childs one by one, but in case of `parent.destroy_all` it doesn't remove the parent record.

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about `parent.delete_all`?  `parent.destroy_all` still calls destroy on each child individually.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:
(1) Child model should not be able to call parent_model.destory, which is against model design pattern.
(2) In parent model after_update callback, check if children.count > 0. destroy if no associations found.